# Adding a UITableView at run time to a UIViewController that has a NavigationBar - y position issue

Tags: uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, swift2, uinavigationbar, ios9.2

I have UIViewController that has a Navigation Bar. At run time, I am adding (on viewDidLoad) a UITable. The problem I have is an inconsistent behaviour of the UITableView y-position.

In viewDidLoad I set the UITableView frame to:

```
tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.frame)
```

then:

```
self.view.addSubview(tableView)
```

The problem: on the odd occasion, and only on iphone 4s, the table is added underneath the NavigationBar *resulting in the first row not being visible* to the user (put another way: y-pos = 0).

If I try to set the y-pos to status bar height + nav bar height the table is always positioned too low (i.e. at the wrong y-pos)

Am I doing something wrong or have I stumbled upon random quirk of ios 9.2 & swift 2?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

Try following in controller's viewDidLoad Method :

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

or You can disable it from Attribute Inspector as given in below image.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm...when I do that then on all phones the first row of the table is masked/hidden by the nav bar. Looking at this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/19129292/1176660, my case is the second one described (the UITableView is the first subview) so in theory, my original settings should work. However, as stated, on iphone 4s + ios 9.2 it sometimes fail (I have two devices - on one it works and on the other it does not :( )