# Why my UITextView text is not show from starting and hide under Navigation Bar

Tags: xcode, swift, uitextview

I wonder why my textview text didn't show up from starting text.
This is the image from my Xcode IB

[image: Image From XCode]

When I run it on my iPhone 6 Simulator and others

[image: Simulator]

Actually it should start from "Example Notification...."

Please help me out.

Comment: select your `view controller -> attribute inspector ->Unselect underTop Bars`

Comment: thats because its behind navigation bar drag it down below navigation bar

Comment: @HamzaAnsari,I know what u are talking about.But,how to appear not under navigation bar?

Comment: Follow @EICaptain instruction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 7 Table view fail to auto adjust content inset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091737/ios-7-table-view-fail-to-auto-adjust-content-inset)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those who didn't start `UITextView` from start,here is the answer.I am sure it worked 100% on iOS 8 and higher on any devices.

1.You need to deselect these at your view controller where textview is applied

**Go to ViewController > Attribute Inspector > Search Extend Edges > Under Top Bars & Under Button Bars**

2.Add the following code at your view controller

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.yourTextView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
}
```

Special Thanks to @El Captain

Comment: Still going strong on iOS 12

Comment: Just ran into this issue and this is the only solid solution for iOS 15.5.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain `UINavigationBar` *translucent* and allow user to rotate the device while reading `UITextView` I used something like this:

```
private var firstLayout = true

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if firstLayout {
        firstLayout = false
        textView.setContentOffset(
            CGPoint(x: 0, y: -topLayoutGuide.length), animated: false)
    }    
}
```

Tested on iOS 9 and iOS 12 Beta.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was iOS 13. UITextView was constrained to edges. It's content was set on did load, after that text view automatically scrolled to the bottom causing large title to shrink.
What helped me is to wrap setText in to async:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    textView.text = logs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also keep UINavigationBar `isTranslucent` and `UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentAutomatic`,

Just to fix the textView is hidden by navigationBar, then add the below code:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [textView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -self.view.layoutMargins.top) animated:NO];
}
```