# Incorrect scrollview insets when Adjust Scroll View Insets is true after orientation changes

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

My project is storyboard based and includes the following controllers:

- UINavigationController.
- UITableViewController - `TableViewController` which contains a list of items.
- UIViewController - `ViewController` which displays details of the item selected in `TableViewController`.

[image: Test project's storyboard]

There's a `UISearchController` inside `TableViewController`, with its `searchBar` set as the `tableHeaderView` of the `tableView`. The gist of `TableViewController` is here:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    private let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
}
```

I've checked (in fact, haven't unchecked) the `Adjust Scroll View Insets` in the Interface Builder for `TableViewController`.

When the user taps on an item in the list, it's segueing to the `ViewController` with the detailed information about the item.

Everything works smoothly in most cases, and `TableViewController` is displayed as expected:

[image: Scroll View Insets Expected]

The issue arises when the user changes orientation in `ViewController` and then segues back to `TableViewController`. The latter in this case has incorrect content inset set for its 'tableView':

[image: Scroll View Insets Issue]

If the search is cancelled before tapping an item the issue is not present.

Recording of the issue on an iOS 9 simulator: https://vimeo.com/182953863.

To make sure there's something wrong with content inset of the table view, I printed the inset in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of `TableViewController`. Here's the output:

```
// Normal mode
UIEdgeInsets(top: 64.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
// After orientation changes in ViewController
UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
```

There're a number of similar questions on SO ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091737/ios-7-table-view-fail-to-auto-adjust-content-inset), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069258/automaticallyadjustsscrollviewinsets-not-working), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924431/ios-7-navigationcontroller-is-setting-the-contentinset-and-contentoffset-of-m)), from which I made two conclusions:

1. If the view controller added is a UITableViewController, the issue should not be appeared since Apple will auto padding it ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19129292/758990)). This is the case, and the issue still appears.
2. Try switching off the `autoAdjustScrollViewInsets` and set the insets manually in the code. This one should definitely work, but I'd like to first find the culprit of the issue.

What I've tried to do:

- Set `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` to `true`. The issue persisted.
- Set `definesPresentationContext` to `false`, and calling `self.view.endEditing(true)` in the `prepareForSegue` of `TableViewController` (this one had no effect). The issue was gone. But the search bar persisted down the hierarchy of the view controllers, namely in `ViewController`, which was not acceptable.
- Resigning first responder for the search bar in `prepareForSegue` by `searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()`. The issue persisted.

I've assembled a [test project](https://github.com/stansidel/auto-adjust-scrollview-insets-issue) which reproduces this issue. The search doesn't work and the list items are hard-coded, but it does reproduce the issue without extra details.

There must be an error in the way I set up the search controller, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I was having the same issue. This answer fixed it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28722390/742298