# Navigation controller issue in container view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uicontainerview

**Phase 1:**

I have a controller embedded inside a navigation controller. I am trying to create a custom container view inside this controller.

**Phase 2:**

I have created xib of UIView which contain scrollView which I am passing in controller initialiser and passing this controller to be added in custom container.

scroll view inset is automatically changing to y: -64.

**Summary of what I tried:**

From this [What does addChildViewController actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192005/what-does-addchildviewcontroller-actually-do) 
I know that parent controller passes navigation to child controller. That is creating this adjustment of inset.

Then I tried to disable the property

> automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets

of controller to false but still its not working

From [iOS 7: Custom container view controller and content inset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065157/ios-7-custom-container-view-controller-and-content-inset) I found out that automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets property also not works on this complicated setup.

**Main Question**

When I am adding the controller created through storyboard containing same setup to container View its working fine. But when I am creating through code, scroll view content inset issue arises. What property I am missing in code thats present in storyboard of UIViewController?

Answer (score 0):

i faced this problem too.
i didn't have much time to dig to this problem.it seems very confusing to me.

but:
  i solved the problem with disable adjust to scroll insets of navigation controller,parent controller,and container view (child) controller, 
and i disabled under opaque bars the problem has solved.