# ContentInset set wrong when dismissing view controller in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xamarin

In my iOS application (developed using Xamarin) I am using a custom container view controller to switch between different child view controllers (which all contain a  `UITableView`) associated with the segments of a  `UISegmentedControl`.

At the beginning I was having an issue with the wrong `contentInset` assigned when switching to a new view controller, as the view was positioned underneath the navigation bar. I solved the issue with the solution presented in this other stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038949/content-falls-beneath-navigation-bar-when-embedded-in-custom-container-view-cont), and it worked like charm.

The problem now is that one of the child view controllers presents another view controller modally, and when it is dismissed, the `contentInset` is set wrong again. In this case with the tableview starting at the middle of the available space, with quite some white space between the navigation bar and the first row.

I was trying to understand which method implicitly changes the content inset, but I no luck. So, what method could be the culprit of this behaviour?

I have tried with setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` both to true and false, but the result is the same.

UPDATE: It seems that the issue is presented only in iOS 8, but not in iOS 7

Comment: Do you have a minimal example? Do you use `UITableViewController` as base class?

Comment: You are likely changing the `contentInset` at a less than optimal time, possibly more than once. Do not take this comment as an answer, for I recommend using the solution below, which does not tinker with the native iOS views.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Synposis**

Get rid of `contentInset`. Insert a `UINavigationController` between the *Segmented Control View Controller* and each *table view controller*.

**How it looks in the Storyboard**

*While you are not required to use a Storyboard to implement this solution, it makes for a very graphic user interface.*

[image]

**Hook up the Segmented Control**

*Again, I use Storyboard for simplicity and clarity. You are welcome to create each navigation controller and view controller programmatically if it suits you.*

This is the **entire** class. 30 lines of code total.

```
class SegmentedControlViewController: UIViewController {
    var segmentViewController:UIViewController? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nav0") as? UIViewController
        self.addChildViewController(vc!)
        self.view.addSubview(vc!.view)
        self.segmentViewController = vc
    }

    @IBAction func segmentedControlValueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let segmentedControl = sender as? UISegmentedControl {
            let identifier = "nav\(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)"
            let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) as? UIViewController

            self.addChildViewController(vc!)
            self.transitionFromViewController(self.segmentViewController!, toViewController: vc!, duration: 0, options: .TransitionNone, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.segmentViewController!.view.removeFromSuperview()
                //vc!.view.frame = self.view.bounds
                self.view.addSubview(vc!.view)
            }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
                vc!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
                self.segmentViewController!.removeFromParentViewController()
                self.segmentViewController = vc
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**Compatibility**

The above code does not show how to push a view controller using Segue `Present Modally` or `Show (e.g. Push) since it is out of the scope of this response and both have been verified.

*Built and tested on iPhone 4s to 6 Plus, every iPad, Portrait, Landscape, orientation changes, iOS 7 & 8.*